# How to inherit in Builder Pattern in java

Tags: inheritance, default-constructor, builder-pattern

I want to inherit a class from a Parent class containing Builder class, but gives compilation error "default constructor not available" in parent class.

I tried building a default constructor for parent class with null values. Yet the default constructor is not called at all, it initializes all values to  null.

1. Product.java

package product;
public class Products {

```
private final String id;          //required
private final String description; //required
private final double price;       //required

public enum Category{
    Electronics,
    Clothing,
    ShowCart
}

private Products(ProductBuilder builder) {
    this.id = builder.id;
    this.description = builder.description;
    this.price = builder.price;
}


public String getID() {
    return id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public static class ProductBuilder {


    private final String id;          //required
    private final String description; //required
    private final double price;       //required

    public ProductBuilder(String id, String description, double price)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
        }


    public Products build(){

        Products prod = new Products(this);
        return prod;
    }

}
```

}

2. Electronic.java

package product;

public  class Electronic extends Products{     //COMPILATION ERROR

```
                                     //DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR NOT AVAILABLE
```

}

I want to make the problem solve without introducing default constructor and neither violate BUILDER PATTERN

Comment: Are you open to using Lombok? https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder. This doesn't answer your question, but should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor to Electronic, and it must call the constructor for its base class. That's standard procedure for an inherited class in Java.

```
public class Electronic extends Products {
  public Electronic(ProductBuilder builder) {
    super(builder);
  }
}
```

If this doesn't make sense, ask yourself this: The base class needs a ProductBuilder. Without this new constructor, how does the base class get its ProductBuilder?